# the swiper height is not correctly calculated, mobile orientation change

Tags: jquery, height, swiper.js

After page load, the swiper height is correct initially.
When resizing window to smaller, the the swiper height is re-calculated correct.
But When resizing window to bigger, the the swiper height is not correctly calculated most of time,
and images are partially hidden.
By most of time, I mean at certain window size, the height is correct.

On mobile Chrome and Safari, when changing orientation,  images are partially hidden. Only after swiping content up and down, the swiper height becomes correct and images are fully visible.

swiper-container and Images width is 100% in order to be responsive.

Thanks for help.

----   code -----

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="idangerous.swiper.css">
<style>
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.pagination {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom:5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.swiper-pagination-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #999;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #555 inset;
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-active-switch {
  background: #fff;
}
</style>

<div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="images/slide1.png"  width="100%"  /> </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="images/slide2.png"  width="100%"  /> </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="content-slide">
            <p class="title">Slide with HTML</p>
            <p>You can put any HTML inside of slide with any layout, not only images, even another Swiper!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>

<script src="idangerous.swiper.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    loop:true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplay:3000,
    roundLengths: true,
    calculateHeight:true
  });
});
</script>

<div>Some content goes here. .... </div>
```